# Kinesis Firehose writes to S3 cloud watch subscription filter but the files are not readable

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I've noticed that Kinesis firehose writes files to kinesis but the files are in non readable human format (probably compressed or binary).
I didn't choose to zip or to encrypt them.

How can i convert the content of this files for human readable format?

Answer (score 4):

Cloud watch logs pipe with firehose to S3  are being automatically  gzip compressed when export to designated S3 bucket.

But Firehose wont add the .gz extension to the file so when you download it from s3 bucket you need to manually add the gz extension to the file.
And then decompress the file delivered to s3 bucket first before opening it.